# Reading and storing data in structs

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to read the file from txt file and store it in a struct. It only reads the first line and 2nd line and then stops. I have a problem in the getdata function on for loop and cannot go any further.

Specification:

- use the number of students to dynamically create an array of Student structures of the exact size
- use the number of students to loop and read in each student info:
- read in the next line and store in the name field
- use the number of scores to dynamically create an array of integers of the exact size
- use the number of scores to loop and store all scores for the student, sum them up, 
     and divide the sum by the max score to get the percentage

Text file:

```
8 6 60
Nayyar, Kunal
10 8 7 10 9 10
Foxx, Redd
8 9 9 10 10 7
Lopez, George
9 6 8 9 10 10
Walters, Barbara
10 8 4 9 7 9
Chan, Jackie
9 9 8 10 10 8
Foxx, Jamie
8 4 10 9 5 7
Cole, Natalie
9 10 8 9 7 9
Liu, Lucy 
9 10 3 7 8 9
```

The first line is number of students, number of scores and maximum scores.
The second line is name of student.
The third line is scores of student 6 each.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Work
{
    int* scores;
    double percent;
};

struct Student
{
    string name; // student name
    Work work;   // scores of student
};

int* getdata();

int main()
{
    Student * stuptr;
    getdata();
}

int * getdata()
{
    ifstream infile;

    infile.open("grades.txt");

    if (!infile)

    {

        cout << "Error opening file\n";

        return 0; // fail to open, return 0

    }
    int num_stu, num_scor, max_sco;
    infile >> num_stu >> num_scor >> max_sco;


    Student * eptr = new Student[num_stu];
    Student name_s[num_stu];
    cout << num_stu << endl;


    int * sptr = new int[num_scor];
    int studentsco[num_scor];
    cout << num_scor << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_stu; i++)
    {
        infile >> name_s[i].name;
        for (int j = 0; j < num_scor; j++)
        {

            infile >> studentsco[j].work.scores;
        }

        cout << name_s[i].name << " ";
        // cout << studentsco[j].work.scores;
        /* infile >> name_s[i].name;
        cout << name_s[i].name << "  ";
        infile >> studentsco[j].work;
        cout << studentsco[j].work << " ";*/
        /* for (int j = 0; j < exact; j++)
        {
            infile >> studentsco[j].work;
            cout << studentsco[j].work << "   ";
        } */

    }
    cout << endl;
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code? What does it do? What does it not do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take note of the formatting that the community has edited into your question.  Take care to format your questions properly, so they can be readable by the community.  Unreadable questions tend to get downvoted and don't usually get answered.

Comment: it read the first line. then it was suppose to read 2nd line using the first for loop and 3rd line using nested for loop. but it jus read the 2nd and 3rd line together and stops looping.

Comment: @user3258843 Is the format of your file more or less the same as what is displayed in this post?

Comment: The first extraction I see you doing is into an integer, but the first line in the file is non-integral, so that won't work.

Comment: yes its in the same format as displayed in this post. @0x499602D2

Comment: the first line of txt file its 8 6 60 @0x499602D2

Comment: Variable-length arrays (VLAs) are non-standard in C++. Therefore doing `Student name_s[num_stu];` is incorrect. You have to do `Student* name_s = new Student[num_stu];` or `std::vector<Student> name_s(num_stu);`

Comment: `infile >> studentsco[j].work.scores;`: You can't do this. `studentsco` is an `int` array and therefore doesn't have data members.

Comment: @0x499602D2 yea its showing me error there how do i fix that?

Comment: @user3258843 I'm writing an answer as we speak.

Comment: I updated my answer. Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: @0x499602D2 but i am not allowed to use vector. let me use reword it and use it in my code. it looks good

Comment: @user3258843 Then I'll have to change my code to use a pointer.

Comment: I think it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure why your original code didn't work, but I would suggest the following changes to your program:

```
#include <iostream>

void getdata(Student& s, int n, std::ifstream& infile)
{
    std::getline(infile >> std::ws, s.name);
    for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    {
        infile >> s.work.scores[k];
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("grades.txt");
    int num_stu, num_scor, max_sco;
    infile >> num_stu >> num_scor >> max_sco;

    Student* students = new Student[num_stu];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_stu; ++i)
    {
        students[i].work.scores = new int[num_scor];
        getdata(students[i], num_scor, infile);
    }
}
```